# How to remove lines from stdout in python?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a program that grabs some data through ssh using paramiko:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.connect(main.Server_IP, username=main.Username, password=main.Password)

ssh_stdin_host, ssh_stdout_host, ssh_stderr_host =ssh_session.exec_command(setting.GetHostData)
```

I would like to remove the first 4 lines from ssh_stdout_host. I've tried using StringIO to use readlines like this:

```
output = StringIO("".join(ssh_stdout_host))
data_all = output.readlines()
```

But I'm lost after this. What would be a good approach? Im using python 2.6.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

readlines provides all the data

```
allLines = [line for line in stdout.readlines()]
data_no_firstfour = "\n".join(allLines[4:])
```

Comment: Google for "python list slice syntax" for all of the cool stuff you can do to lists this way.

Comment: Also I have used Paramiko and I was not sure if stdout.readlines() returns an iterator or the complete list of lines. The first line of the above code would be superflous if it returns a list. But I guess this makes sure that the code won't fault.

Answer (score 6):

**How to remove lines from stdout in python?**

(this is a general answer for removing lines from the stdout **Python console window**, and has nothing to do with specific question involving paramiko, ssh etc)

see also: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804521/how-to-remove-lines-from-stdout-in-python-in-scite-idle-eclipse-or-other-edit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248076/python-how-to-modify-edit-the-string-printed-to-screen-and-read-it-back/7248907#7248907)

Instead of using the `print` command or `print()` function, use `sys.stdout.write("...")` combined with `sys.stdout.flush()`. To erase the written line, go 'back to the previous line' and overwrite all characters by spaces using `sys.stdout.write('\r'+' '*n)`, where `n` is the number of characters in the line.

---

a nice example says it all:

```
import sys, time

print ('And now for something completely different ...')
time.sleep(0.5)

msg = 'I am going to erase this line from the console window.'
sys.stdout.write(msg); sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' '*len(msg))
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(0.5)

print('\rdid I succeed?')
time.sleep(1)
```

**edit**
instead of `sys.stdout.write(msg); sys.stdout.flush()`, you could also use

```
print(msg, end='')
```

For Python versions below 3.0, put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script/module for this to work.

Note that this solution works for the stdout Python console window, e.g. run the script by right-clicking and choosing 'open with -> python'. It does not work for SciTe, Idle, Eclipse or other editors with incorporated console windows. I am waiting myself for a solution for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804521/how-to-remove-lines-from-stdout-in-python-in-scite-idle-eclipse-or-other-edit).