# Starting raw_input() with pre determined text

Tags: python, raw-input

I'd like to be able to get input from the user (through `raw_input()` or a module) and be able to have text automatically be already entered that they can add to, delete, or modify. I know in javascript when you're using a prompt, you can do it like

```
var = prompt("Enter your name: ","put name here")
```

and it will appear as:

```
Enter your name:
put name here
```

where `'put name here'` is in the text box and can be modified. I'm hoping to implement this in a shell environment (I use unix) as opposed to a window.

Any ways to do this?

Oh and tell me if I need to clarify what I am hoping for more.

---

I don't think you guys understand what I'm trying to do.

I basically want to include the prompt in the input, but have the user be able to backspace out the prompt/edit it if they want.

The script would possibly be used for a simple shell based one line text editor, and a tab completion type thing.

Comment: This is *really difficult*. Consider saying `Enter your name [Default Name]: ` and inserting `Default Name` if the input is the empty string; that’s pretty standard for scripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: how to modify/edit the string printed to screen and read it back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248076/python-how-to-modify-edit-the-string-printed-to-screen-and-read-it-back)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On UNIX and UNIX-alikes, such as Mac OS X and Linux, you can use the [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module. On Windows you can use [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline).

If you do it the way minitech suggests in his comment, write a little function to make it easier:

```
def input_default(prompt, default):
    return raw_input("%s [%s] " % (prompt, default)) or default

name = input_default("What is your name?", "Not Sure")
```

Answer (score 3):

Mmm, kinda hack, but try this one.

Windows:

```
import win32com.client as win

shell = win.Dispatch("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("Put name here")
raw_input("Enter your name: ")
```

In Linux/Unix environment, you can use the `pyreadline`, `readline` or `curses` libraries. You can find one possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible):

```
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
    readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    finally:
        readline.set_startup_hook()
```