# How to delete a word in a column using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

| County |
| --- |
| Davis County |
| Ark County |
| Clay County Party |

I want to delete County from the County column. This is what I have tried so far.

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace(['\bCounty\b'], '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string by prefixing with `r`:

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace([r'\bCounty\b'], '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```

The problem is that normally, `\b` is interpreted as a [backspace character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56582609/11659881). You can similarly escape this character by writing `\\b` instead, but it is easier here to just use the raw string.

You also don't have to pass your regex inside of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
def county(df):
    df['County'].replace(' County', '', regex = True, inplace = True)
```